# What is interface-based proxying?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, spring-jdbc, transactional

I was reading this regarding to where to place Transactional(interface vs implementation):

> The Spring team's recommendation is that you only annotate concrete classes with the @Transactional annotation, as opposed to annotating interfaces. You certainly can place the @Transactional annotation on an interface (or an interface method), but **this will only work as you would expect it to if you are using interface-based proxies.** The fact that annotations are not inherited means that if you are using class-based proxies then the transaction settings will not be recognised by the class-based proxying infrastructure and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy (which would be decidedly bad). So please do take the Spring team's advice and only annotate concrete classes (and the methods of concrete classes) with the @Transactional annotation.

So the question is what is *interface-based proxy* exactly and how can I see if it is used? Is it some configuration or it is the way how I instantiate/use instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Spring cannot create a JDK proxy (or if you force Spring to create a CGLIB proxy by setting [proxyTargetClass](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html#aop-pfb-proxy-types) to true) then the code will not execute in a transactional context because (as the Spring docs state):

> The fact that annotations are not inherited means that if you are using class-based proxies then the transaction settings will not be recognised by the class-based proxying infrastructure and the object will not be wrapped in a transactional proxy

So, I think your concerns are:

> How can you be sure that Spring does not create a CGLIB proxy

You must be configuring AOP based transactional support. If you are doing this by using `<tx:annotation-driven/>` then the default value for proxy-target-class (false) will suffice though could be explicit about this by setting: `<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class=“false"></tx:annotation-driven>`. If you are configuring transactional support in some other way (using Java config, for example) then just ensure that the value of `TransactionProxyFactoryBean.proxyTargetClass` is false.

> How can you be sure that your @Transactional annotations are respected

This is easy, just annotate the concrete class with the `@Transactional` annotation instead of annotating the interfaces. This avoids any issues with proxying.

In summary, Spring should use interface based proxying as long as `TransactionProxyFactoryBean.proxyTargetClass` is false however, if you annotate a concrete class rather than an implementation then the issue of proxying won't affect transactional support.

Comment: also add to the answer that spring cant create proxy if class is final or create a few proxies for one class